# How to move object between dictionaries?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, collections

I have simple task where I need to check objects in one dictionary and if certain criteria met move to another. What I am asking if there is some good pattern where I can use language feature to achieve that. The straight approach is simple - use temporaty collection, first step determine canditates, second step do actual move. It is ok but it is not cool.

Current code

```
class Order
{
  public int ID;
  public bool IsReady;
}

Dictionary<int, Order> ActiveDictionary;
Dictionary<int, Order> ProcessedDictionary;

public Update()
{    
 // temporary list, uncool
 List<Order> processed = new List<Order>();


 // fist step
 foreach(Order ord in ActiveDictionary)
 {
  if(ord.IsReady)
  {
    processed.Add(ord);
  }
 }

 // ok now lets move
 foreach(Order ord in processed)
 {
  ActiveDictionary.Remove(ord.ID);
  ProcessedDictionary.Add(ord.ID, ord);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing really wrong with the code you have.

As an exercise in alternatives, you could do something like...

```
ProcessedDictionary = ProcessedDictionary
    .Concat(
        ActiveDictionary.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Ready)
    )
    .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);

ActiveDictionary = ActiveDictionary.Where(kvp => !kvp.Value.Ready)
    .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Comment: I have got a feeling you really want to use `Where` and not `Select`. I doubt the code compiles as it is now, since the input to `ToDictionary` is probably a `bool` value.

Comment: @Fredrik still adjusting to the time difference... and your amazing early winter!

Comment: Cool, but ProcessedDictionary is overriden isn't? The old values will be lost

Comment: @Captain yes, it would be. See my revised answer for how to handle that.

Comment: +1: Interesting approach, but any client that is holding onto a reference to the old dictionary wouldn't see the changes.

Comment: @Rex: oh, you are here in Scandinavia? Your profile says US. And sure, early winter this year. Turns commuting into a small adventure every day :)

Comment: @Fredrik live in US but since I work for Volvo I get to spend time in Gothenburg :)

Comment: Two nitpicks: This method loops all elements of ActiveDictionary twice, rather than looping ActiveDictionary once and then looping over only the items that are being moved. If ActiveDictionary is large and the number of processed elements is small this is a lot of wasted work. Also, while I find it VERY instructive in terms of what can be done, I think it's hard to understand the intent of the code (obviously a quick code comment or putting the snippet into a well-named method would fix that).

Comment: @mcl this is intended to be a thought exercise in alternatives, not legitimate proposals at production code. I've modified my answer to make that clear.

Comment: @Rex, it certainly works in that regard. Forces one to consider the snippet carefully but also shows off some of the newer C#/.NET capabilities that might otherwise be less well known.

Answer (score 3):

if **Rex M**'s answer is not suitable (maybe you don't want to rebuild Dictionaries on each iteartion), then as small improvement I can suggest to replace

```
// temporary list, uncool
List<Order> processed = new List<Order>();

// fist step
foreach(Order ord in ActiveDictionary)
{
  if(ord.IsReady)
  {
     processed.Add(ord);
  }
}
```

to

```
var processed = ActiveDictionary.Where(x=>x.Value.Ready).ToArray();
```

and the rest of your code would be

```
foreach(var item in processed)
{
   ActiveDictionary.Remove(item.Key);
   ProcessedDictionary.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
}
```

UPD: As **Ani** commented, there is another alike solution:

```
var processed = ActiveDictionary.Values.Where(x=>x.Ready).ToArray();

foreach(var item in processed)
{
   ActiveDictionary.Remove(item);
   ProcessedDictionary.Add(item.Id, item);
}
```

Comment: I like this answer because the intent of the code is quite clear from reading it: "Find all elements like this and remove/add them from the dictionaries"

Comment: I like LINQ a lot. But sometimes it's just not the place for it. This answer is that case: old-good style with small mix of LINQ is much more readable fully-LINQ style.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var keys = ActiveDictionary
    .Where(kv => kv.Value.Ready)
    .Select(kv => kv.Key).ToList();
keys.ForEach(k =>
        {
            ProcessedDictionary.Add(k, ActiveDictionary[k]);
            ActiveDictionary.Remove(k);
        });
```

Comment: If you don't do .Select(kv => kv.Key) then you won't need to search for value in ActiveDictionary (when you add items in Foreach).